# Styled-components: How to refer to the same component but with different props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `Container` component, which takes a prop `fluid` as `boolean`.

```
const Container = styled.div`
  ${({ fluid }) => ...}
`
```

I want to nest it in a `Navbar` component but different prop value. I read [styled-components' doc about referring to other components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components), but the example code is simple. Here's what I want

```
const Navbar = styled.nav`
  /* Previous styles */

  ${Container // When fluid is false} {
    /* Some styles*/
  }

  ${Container // When fluid is true} {
    /* Some styles (different from above) */
  }
`
```

or in CSS.

```css
.navbar {
  /* Previous styles */

  .container {
    /* Some styles */
  }

  .container-fluid {
    /* Some styles */
  }
}
```

Have any ideas to make that happen? Every comments are appreciated to me.

Comment: In my opinion, you can create a common styled-components then you can extend this with some different props

Comment: but how do I extend that?